# jQuery queuing css methods

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transitions, chaining

I have discovered some behavior, that seems quite strange, to my understanding, how jQuery.css() works. I know, it is not queuable, but in the fiddle below, when I apply 2 css method in succession - but not in one queue, it behaves differently, that applying them with 1ms delay by setTimeout.

The result is, that one box fades in, but the other goes immediately to opacity 1.

Can somebody clarify please.

```js
var fadingBox = $("<div></div>")
  .css({
    "opacity": "0"
  })
  .appendTo("#cont");


setTimeout(function() {
  fadingBox.css({
    "background": "red",
    "opacity": "1"
  });
}, 1);


var notFadingBox = $("<div></div>")
  .css({
    "background": "red",
    "opacity": "0"
  })
  .appendTo("#cont");


notFadingBox.css("opacity", "1");
```

```css
div {
  -webkit-transition: opacity 2s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 2s;
  -ms-transition: opacity 2s;
  -o-transition: opacity 2s;
  transition: opacity 2s;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cont">

</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lukis/0mbz7e9x/35/

EDIT: Updated the jsFiddle, which was wrong before.

Comment: Please explain the difference you are seeing and what we should look for in demo

Comment: The fiddle was wrong, sorry for that. Now it shows the problem. When you run it, one box fades in slowly, the other one shows immediatelly. No idea why.

Comment: Please include all relevant code. In this case, looking at the fiddle, you have a `transition` in CSS, which is not displayed here in the question. Those without access to jsfiddle would be unable to answer the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser's layout engine cannot differentiate between the beginning state and end state of your element because, in its eyes, both the beginning state (`opacity: 0`) and end state (`opacity: 1`) were set at the same time.

In order for the layout engine to understand that there should be separation, you'll need to cause an interruption between the beginning and end. Unfortunately, as far as I'm aware, there isn't a legitimate or "nice" way to do this, so you need to utilize a workaround.

`setTimeout` is one way to force a separation, which is why your first example works.

*(This method is commonly misunderstood, so I feel it important to clarify that this does not work because you're "giving the browser time", but rather because `setTimeout` creates a queued callback. This callback is then executed separately, bypassing the initial issue of setting both states at the same time.)*

See the example below, where I set the timeout to `0` and still get a proper transition:

```js
var $fadingBox= $("<div></div>")
    .css({"background" : "red","opacity": "0"})
    .appendTo("#cont");

setTimeout(function(){
    $fadingBox.css("opacity", "1");
}, 0);
```

```css
#cont div {
  transition: 2s opacity;
  padding: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cont"></div>
```

Some functions also cause layout engine interruption/refresh, although I wouldn't always depend on these working, as you're capitalizing on something that may be removed in future optimizations.

For example, you could take advantage of an element's `offsetHeight` property, whose getter function causes the layout engine to "pause":

```js
var $fadingBox = $("div");
$fadingBox.css("opacity", "0");
$fadingBox[0].offsetHeight;      //LAYOUT ENGINE REFRESH
$fadingBox.css("opacity", "1");
```

```css
div {
  background: red;
  transition: 2s opacity;
  padding: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

Comment: ...or you could use `delay` and `queue` https://jsfiddle.net/RokoCB/rnd1gsez/1/ if `setTimeout` feels *hackish*

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Very true, I definitely should have mentioned that. However - despite the example *including* jQuery - I was writing it with plain JS in mind.

Comment: Cool, thanks :-). If you want to elaborate more, I have one more Q. I knew that "giving browser time" wasn't the thing and I was actually trying to solve it with just encapsulating the second .css() in { code block }. But what causes the layout engine to refresh normally? Because I would not consider two separate .css() calls to be "same time" any more than the setTimeout hack is. Is it the context switch that does the job?

Comment: Correct. The layout engine will consolidate anything in the same function call (all the way up to the page-level). The `setTimeout` callback has to be made in a separate event, so the layout engine doesn't initially combine the two `.css` calls - as far as it's concerned, the `setTimeout` will be handled later. It doesn't care when, it just knows enough to ignore the `setTimeout` entirely for now.

Comment: One more observation I made. You can force the layout engine to NOT combine those two by asking jQuery to get position of that element between those 2 css calls